# ios app rebuilds but doesn't transfer to simulator correctly on changes

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I updated my @nativescript/ios to 7.1.1 and now when I build to the simulator it works the first time. Then if I make a change it tries to update but the app goes white and will not allow for the transfer of the update. I have to control-c out of the ns command and re-run it to get the update to copy over.

```
✔ Component nativescript has 7.1.2 version and is up to date.
✔ Component @nativescript/core has 7.1.4 version and is up to date.
✔ Component @nativescript/ios has 7.1.1 version and is up to date.
✔ Component @nativescript/android has 7.0.1 version and is up to date.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try starting it from xCode and see the reported errors.